# Solutions of $32p^7-q^7 = \pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am solving a problem and the original problem is equivalent to proving that there are no positive integers $p,q$ such that $32p^7-q^7 = \pm 1$.

Comment: Observation: $q\equiv\pm1\pmod{32}$

Comment: Please mention the original problem as well, so that if possible we could suggest a way of solving it without solving this question, which could even be harder than the earlier one.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It's a special case of Mihailescu's theorem. It's not hard to find the original problem.

Comment: just consider mod $29$